# Ways to handle package manager security updates in Docker images

Tags: docker, security, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

It is relatively easy to handle base image updates with Docker. On Docker Hub, it is completely automated. Custom CI systems are easily scripted to watch base image IDs.

For what I can't find a good solution is handling updates INSIDE the image of software handled by package managers, like apt.

For example, consider a Docker image that starts from debian:stretch and  installs openssl and ca-certificates. How could one automatically rebuild the image when one of those packages receives an update in the apt repository? None of the usual approaches handle this sitation, since neither a SCM change, nor a base image change happens.

In my opinion, the correct way to handle this would be to detect package updates in the image, rebuild the image and let Kubernetes/Docker hosts automatically restart containers when their image is updated in the repository. (if you want automatic container updates - which I do)

The ONLY way I can think of is to run a script on the CI that runs the image, but replaces the CMD instruction with a script that returns a number of available package upgrades and forces a --no-cache build if the number is greater than 0. This kinda replicates the behaviour of unattended-upgrades, but much more fitting for a container environment like Docker.

This could then be run periodically, e.g. every hour, and would automatically push new images when package upgrades are available.

Is anyone doing something like this or has a comparable solution for the problem? Our workaround is to simply rebuild all images daily with --no-cache, even if nothing changed. While this works, it is horribly wasteful on resources and forces unnecessary daily container restarts.